# Docker Container nvidia/k8s-device-plugin:1.9 Keeps Reporting Error

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gpu, kubectl, nvidia-docker

I am trying to setup one small kubenertes cluster on my ubuntu 18.04 LTS server. Now every step is done, but checking the GPU status fails. The container keeps reporting errors:

**1. Issue Description**
     I have done steps by [Quick-Start](https://github.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin#quick-start), but when I run the test case, it reports error.

**2. Steps to reproduce the issue**

- exec shell cmd

  > docker run --security-opt=no-new-privileges --cap-drop=ALL
  >   --network=none -it -v /var/lib/kubelet/device-plugins:/var/lib/kubelet/device-plugins
  >   nvidia/k8s-device-plugin:1.9
- check the erros

  > 2020/02/09 00:20:15 Starting to serve on 
  >   /var/lib/kubelet/device-plugins/nvidia.sock
  >   2020/02/09 00:20:15 Could not register device plugin: rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc =
  >   unknown service deviceplugin.Registration
  >   2020/02/09 00:20:15 Could
  >   not contact Kubelet, retrying. Did you enable the device plugin
  >   feature gate?
  >   2020/02/09 00:20:15 You can check the prerequisites at:
  >   https://github.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin#prerequisites
  >   2020/02/09
  >   00:20:15 You can learn how to set the runtime at:
  >   https://github.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin#quick-start

**3. Environment Information**
   - outputs of **nvidia-docker run --rm dlws/cuda nvidia-smi**

> NVIDIA-SMI 440.48.02 Driver Version: 440.48.02 CUDA Version: 10.2

- outputs of **nvidia-docker run --rm dlws/cuda nvidia-smi**

> NVIDIA-SMI 440.48.02 Driver Version: 440.48.02 CUDA Version: 10.2

- contents of **/etc/docker/daemon.json**

contents:

```
{
"default-runtime": "nvidia",
"runtimes": {
    "nvidia": {
        "path": "nvidia-container-runtime",
        "runtimeArgs": []
    }
}
```

}

- docker version: **19.03.2**
- kubernetes version: **1.15.2**

Comment: you ask about kubernetes but then run docker command: it doesn't make any sense. also you didn't even provided what error you get from the test case. finally you need to explain with details how did you setup your cluster.

Comment: @morgwai reedited the post, and gave an answer I have found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer, hope this post would be helpful for others who encounter the same issue:

**For kubernetes 1.15, use k8s-device-plugin:1.11 instead**. The version 1.9 is not able to communicate with kubelet.

Comment: Where is the plugin version compatibility documented, and how do I find my version of the plugin?